# Javascript location.replace and iframe

Tags: javascript

Following program can work in chrome, but in the firefox not work, I need to refresh the page, otherwise the page will be blank!

The firefox will jump out of the store window to use iframe will not work, there are ways around this?

thanks all!

```
var url = "/card/"+dl_path;
SaveFrame.document.location.replace(url);

<iframe id="SaveFrame" style="display: none"></iframe>
```

Comment: @Christoph This is *Firefox*

Comment: @VisioN well, the same typo twice made it an option it's a browser/chrome extension/whatever which I haven't come across yet;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you can use something like `$('#saveFrame').attr('src', url)`. It should work for all browsers.

Comment: I don't think this should be the answer to this specific question, since this is a jQuery-based solution and OP asked for a JavaScript solution. The question is not tagged with jQuery anyway. There is no additional elaboration.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
document.getElementById('SaveFrame').src="http://google.com/";
```

Comment: Could you please eloborate a bit?

Answer (score 1):

**This should work and it is fast loading for the webpage**
It worked for me...

```
onmouseover="window.open ('http://www.yourpage.com','YourTargetName'); this.onmouseover=null;"
```

The code "this.onmouseover=null;" means that it should only do it ONCE when it loads and not repeat the the attribute on a second mouse over, if you want it to repeat the attribute on a second mouse over then delete the "this.onmouseover=null;" from the code and make it look like this to load each time mouse is over:

```
onmouseover="window.open ('http://www.yourpage.com','YourTargetName');"
```

EXAMPLE:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="window.open ('http://www.yourpage.com','YourTargetName');">
My Link</a>
```

**Or try this:**

```
OnClick="window.open ('http://www.yourpage.com','YourTargetName');"
```

EXAMPLE:

```
<a href="#" OnClick="window.open ('http://www.yourpage.com','YourTargetName');">
My Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:window.open ('http://www.yourpage.com','YourTargetName');">
My Link</a>
```

or

If you wish to use `window.location.replace` to not update the history when loading the page or the frame, use links that look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="YourTargetName.location.replace ('http://www.YourPage.com');">
The targeted Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:YourTargetName.location.replace ('http://www.YourPage.com');">
The targeted Link</a>
```

***information:*** For this script all `onclick`, `onmouseover`, `onmouseout` , `onload` and `href="javascript:"` will work.

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that the iframe has to have the name="YourTargetName", for example to look something like this:

```
<iframe id="SaveFrame" style="display: none" name="YourTargetName"></iframe>
```

***Information:*** The difference between `window.open` and `window.location.replace` or `YourTargetName.location.replace` is that:
 - `window.open` loads in the browser history.
 - `window.location.replace` or `YourTargetName.location.replace` does not load history.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing an element via a variable which is implicitely created in the global scope is a proprietary "Internet Explorer" way that is most likely to going not work in other browsers (although Chrome supports this due to compatability reasons). You should always address an element through a Dom Selection Method either via:

```
document.querySelector(id)
// or
document.getElementById(id)
```

For your case that would be:

```
document.getElementId('SaveFrame').contentDocument.location.replace(url);
// or
document.getElementId('SaveFrame').src= url;
```